# Rearranging divs within a flex column?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have grids within a grid in the following html, for mobile i want to get rid of the middle column and rearrange the other divs in a different order. The grid is arranged on desktop to be more like a timeline so when I place it into mobile i want the timeline vertical line to be removed and instead I want just the text bubbles to be placed in the correct order that I want.

```css
#flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.container1>div:nth-of-type(1) {
  order: 1;
}

.container2>div:nth-of-type(1) {
  order: 2;
}

.container1>div:nth-of-type(2) {
  order: 3;
}

.container2>div:nth-of-type(2) {
  order: 4;
}

.container1>div:nth-of-type(3) {
  order: 5;
}

.three-column-grid>div:nth-of-type(2) {
  order: 6;
}
```

```html
<div class="three-column-grid" id="flex">
  <div class="container1">
    <div>
      <h6>Locate area on map</h6>
      <p>The app allows users to zoom into an area in a city where their searches will be located</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h6>Filter for the category</h6>
      <p>User is able to select the categories he is interested in, in this case user would select nightlife and food</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h6>Share Event to Story</h6>
      <p>The app allows user to interact with an event by sharing through text or sharing to your story so others can see what you're up to. This makes it easier for Andrews friends to see where they are going</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div id="vertical-line" class="container3">
      <span class="dot"></span>
      <span class="dot"></span>
      <span class="dot"></span>
      <span class="dot"></span>
      <span class="dot"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container2">
    <div id="container-box-1">
      <h6>Set date for availability</h6>
      <p>Under the filter section, select which time frame you are looking for, in this case user would select "TONIGHT"</p>
    </div>
    <div id="container-box-2">
      <h6>Select event</h6>
      <p>Selecting the specific event allows for information to pop up about the event where there are several interaction options</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If anyone has a better way please help!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Grid template](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template)

It allows you to declare your grid in this form:

```css
grid-template: "a a a"
               "b b c";
```

and name your elements in this form:

```css
grid-area: a;
```

#### example:

- [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_grid-template-areas3)

Comment: OP is not using a real css-grid but flexboxes

Answer (score 0):

Try using display grid with grid-template-areas and you could move any grid-area in order you want like this:

```css
.grid {
  width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 5px;
  grid-template-areas: 'text1 text2 text3';
}

.item {
  width: auto;
  height: 100px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
}

.text1 {
  grid-area: text1;
  background-color: red;
}

.text2 {
  grid-area: text2;
  background-color: blue;
}

.text3 {
  grid-area: text3;
  background-color: green;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .grid {
    grid-template-areas: 'text3 text2 text2''text1 text1 text1';
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="item text1">text1</div>
  <div class="item text2">text2</div>
  <div class="item text3">text3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: despite the fact, that a grid anwser has already be give: Your grid layout differs from the intend layout of the OP. Actually talkign about a grid-layout is completely wrong as we talk about `flex-direction: column`. Unless a specific height is given, the elements will be displayed below eachother. There is no need to try to solve it with the use of css-grid that is not supported by IE.